# How to increase a grid using this equation on desmos?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, desmos

So, I have a pretty big equation on [desmos (this link is the project)](https://www.desmos.com/geometry/akgr9zzrus), based on linear transformations, which looks like this:

[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUriL.png)

The important part of this equation is the part starting from floor and ending at -19. The equation spits out the number -10 21 times, then -9 21 times, then -8 21 times, and so on up to 20. I am trying to increase the amount this counts up by, but it seems like it's stuck at mapping values from -20 and 20. I'm not sure if this is a rational question, but I haven't figured out a solution yet.

The equation is in the "Vector Grid" section.

Edit: I found how to use LaTeX, so here is the equation.

$$
\operatorname{floor}\left(\sum_{n=-187}^{\left[1...21\operatorname{count}\left(L\right)\right]}\frac{1}{21}\right)-19
$$

Comment: Nice desmos project!

Comment: An "Equation" will have an "equal" sign. That is what the word means: it equates two expressions. What you have could be called a "formula" or (as I just did) an "expression". Also, what does that $[1\dots 21\ count(L)]$ as the upper limit of the summation mean? The upper limit of a summation should be number. How does this define a number? And as the summand is constant, why is this being expressed as a summation at all, instead of just $\bigg([1\dots 21\ count(L)] + 187\bigg)/21$?